# Facebook login with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm writing a asp.net MVC app and trying to log in using Facebook.

I have created an app at Facebook and the log in seams to work, but when I return I don't come to the page where I can assign the facebook accont to a e-mail on my app.

In the code below the loginInfo is null and I'm being redirected to login page again.
Have I forgot to do something or what is happening here? (I have not registered before with the Facebook account I'm logging in with)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since I did a login via Facebook, but could be 2 things.

You need to register with Facebook and add the following to your startup.auth file

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
                appId: "*****",
                appSecret: "*****");
```

Also, I think you have to let Facebook know the return url, not 100% sure as stated earlier, been almost a year since last work with Facebook app.

The following url should help you

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Hope it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1)First go to the https://developers.facebook.com and create your account and get your appid and appsecret 2)go to autoconfig and provide your appid and appsecret in your .net mvc application 3)in devloper of facebook go to setting in bottom site url option give your url which is like http://localhots..... 4)than in devloper of facebook side go to add product tab and choos facebook plugin 5)than Enable -Client oayth login -web oauth login -embeeded browser login 6)than in devloper of facebook go to the app review 7)choose yes for make live 8)enjoy .....hope it work if any query ask me...